# Prevent dropdown until all options are completely added jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding options to my dropdown dynamically on click event. My problem is the dropdown drops before even all options are finished adding and user can see the appending of options.

My Code is something like below.

```
$(document).on('click', '.someDropdown', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<option class="someClass" value="foo">Foo</option>');
});
```

How can I make sure the dropdown drops after all the options are finished adding?

Comment: `disable` it and after appending `enable` it.

Comment: I am appending after the click event on the dropdown. What is the use of disabling after clicking?

Comment: You can't use `click` for `dropdown`. Use`change` event for `dropdown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.someDropdown', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<option class="someClass" value="foo">Foo</option>');
});
```

The mousedown event occurs when the left mouse button is pressed down over the selected element.

The [mousedown()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mousedown.asp) method triggers the mousedown event, or attaches a function to run when a mousedown event occurs.

Comment: Do you mean to say, unless the function attached to mousedown won't finish executing, the click event won't execute its task?

Comment: Mousedown triggered when mouse pressed, click triggered when mouse pressed and released. Mousedown function will finish executing before click.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You might want to add touchstart as well to make it mobile friendly.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide your someDropdown before appending and show it after the appending

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your dropdown is JS controlled, and you actually have two click handlers for your dropdown: one to show the dropdown and one to append the options. This is creating a race condition. If you control your dropdown through css, you can eliminate the race condition and append the options before your dropdown shows.

```
$(document).on('click', '.someDropdown', function(e) {
   $(this).append('<option class="someClass" value="foo">Foo</option>');
   $(this).addClass('enabled');
});
```

Comment: I have changed click to mousedown event to achieve the goal.

Comment: Awesome! Probably the easier route :)